# python selenium timeout exception does not pass compiling

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I have some Selenium WebDRiver code that searches for the "Next" button and if it exists, it clicks it. If not, the script should catch `TimeoutException` and continue.

Code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def clicking_next_page():
    btn_next_to_click=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='next']")))
    try:
        btn_next_to_click.click()
        crawler()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the line that actually times out in the `try-catch`. Simply move the `WebDriverWait` line down inside the `try`.

```
def clicking_next_page():
    try:
        btn_next_to_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='next']")))
        btn_next_to_click.click()
        crawler()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```